# How can I retrieve text from an external URL in After Effects using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scripting, extendscript, after-effects

I'm trying to create a plugin for After Effects 2023 using Microsoft Visual Studio Code. But I'm fairly new for creating something like that. I stuck at working on getting text from the url. I've actually uploaded both test.txt and test.json (tried one by one ) files to my hosting and trying to reach the text inside. I've managed to get the text if I use .txt file on locally but the important part is taking text from my web page.

To be more clear, I've a button called Get Text on my UI, and I've uploaded test.txt file which includes a number for testing to my hosting. How can i reach that .text/.json files and get the text from them? I failed everytime to getting texts.

I've tried to use XMLHttpRequest, sockets and Fetch. But as I've said before I'm fairly new at this so not sure if I made everything correctly

Example;

```
var url = "https://example.com/plugin/test.txt";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url, false);
  xhr.send();

  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    var content = xhr.responseText;
    if (content === "50") {
      alert("Yup,it's 50!");
    } else {
      alert("Nope!");
    }
  } else {
    alert("Error: " + xhr.status);
  }
}
```